# How to run a specific cronjob from a group from the console, in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cron

This is my crontab.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="my_special_group_name">
        <job instance="path\to\my\class" method="execute" name="my_special_cron_name">
            <schedule>*/2 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>

    </group>
</config>
```

By running `bin/magento cron:run --group="my_special_group_name"` I am getting the message of `Ran jobs by schedule.` , but i want to know what is the equivalent of the command `./n98-magerun.phar sys:cron:run my_special_cron_name`  ? using the `bin/magento`

Thnx for the help in advance!

Comment: The n98 magerun cli tools provides some handy tools to work with Magento from command line.

Comment: https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2

Comment: @RkRathod yes I know . Is there an equivalent command  for `./n98-magerun.phar sys:cron:run my_special_cron_name` using `bin/magento` . ? That is my question. If YES, which one ?

Comment: no i think not,,

Comment: is there another way to run a specific cronjob ?  from the console , except of course using magerun ?